# How do I combine a mysql and linux bash script?

Tags: mysql, shell, stored-procedures

I have to read some columns from mysql and change that column using bash script and then update column in mysql. 
My Mysql query is like "select description from story".
Then i will iterate over each row of the result set and edit the description with some shell scripting. After editing i will update that row . 
The pseudo code looks like :

```
select id,description from story
for each description in result set
   $orig_description=description
   $orig_id= id
   apply shell script file script.sh ($edited_description=./script.sh)
   update story set description=$edited_description where id=$orig_id
```

What is the easiest way to accomplish this task ? And how to accomplish it ?

Answer (score 2):

As per your given queries and explanation,sample script would be,

```
cmd="mysql -u [user] -p[pass]"
cmdRes=$($cmd -e "select id,description from story")

for val in "$cmdRes";
do

#parse val for id and description 
#val1=id
#val2=description

#apply modification logic

$cmd -e "update story set desc=${Val2} where id=${val1}"

done
```